# Getting blank value on retrieves a single asset for a theme in shopify asset API Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

Getting blank value on retrieves a single asset for a theme

Retrieve a Liquid template:

```
GET /admin/api/2020-04/themes/#{theme_id}/assets.json?asset[key]=templates/index.liquid
```

When I have call this API but getting blank value.

My code:

```
$shop->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/api/2020-04/themes/#{theme_id}/assets.json?asset[key]=layout/theme.liquid);
```

API response:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer of my question in the docs for osiset/laravel-shopify which is the API wrapper implemented in the laravel-shopify package. The url parameter needs to be passed as a separate parameter to the rest method, like so:

```
$assets = $shop->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/api/2020-04/themes/#{theme_id}/assets.json', ['asset[key]' => 'snippets/collection-grid-item.liquid']);
```

I have found solution from https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/wiki/Usage